# IntersectionObserver method not working - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, dom-events, intersection-observer

I have a div that I want to change color when it scrolls into the viewport, and I'm trying to achieve this with the new `intersectionObserver` method. I've set my parameters in the config callback, but I can't seem to get the observer itself to add the class to change the background color?

Any help would be amazing.

codepen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/mXVBVK

```js
const config = {
  root: null,  // sets the framing element to the viewport
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 0.5
};

const box = document.getElementById('box');

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
  observer.observe(box);
  entries.forEach(function(item){
    item.classList.add("active");
  });
}, config);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 300vh;
}

#box {
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;}

.active {background: red;}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The function inside the `IntersectionObserver` constructor is called whenever an intersection changes. You can’t put `observer.observe(box);` inside it.

Also, `item` isn’t a DOM element — it’s an `IntersectionObserverEntry`, so you can’t use `.classList` on it. You probably meant to address `item.target`.

Even if the above is corrected, your CSS won’t change, because you’ve used the `#box` selector to set the `background` to `blue`, which has a higher specificity than `.active`. An easy fix is to change `#box` to `.box` and as HTML use `<div id="box" class="box"></div>` instead.

The corrected code would then look like this:

```js
const config = {
    root: null, // Sets the framing element to the viewport
    rootMargin: "0px",
    threshold: 0.5
  },
  box = document.getElementById("box"),
  observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => entries
    .forEach(({ target: { classList } }) => classList.add("active")), config);

observer.observe(box);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 300vh;
}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="box"></div>
```

Now you need some logic inside the callback:

```
entries.forEach(({ target: { classList }, intersectionRatio }) => {
  if(intersectionRatio >= 0.5){
    classList.add("active");
  }
  else{
    classList.remove("active");
  }
});
```

This will make the `<div>` red when 50 % or more of it is visible. The observer will stop firing after 50 % or more is visible, so in some cases `intersectionRatio` will be exactly `0.5`.

```js
const config = {
    root: null, // Sets the framing element to the viewport
    rootMargin: "0px",
    threshold: 0.5
  },
  box = document.getElementById("box"),
  observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => entries
    .forEach(({ target: { classList }, intersectionRatio }) => {
      if(intersectionRatio >= 0.5){
        classList.add("active");
      }
      else{
        classList.remove("active");
      }
    }), config);

observer.observe(box);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 300vh;
}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="box"></div>
```